# Turning values that can not be changed from str to int into nan value in a column

Tags: python, data-wrangling

I am trying to assign `NaN` to values in a column that can not be changed from str to int. For example, `04` can be changed to int while `Or` can not be.

Comment: Have you tried using a regex as you need digits only?

Comment: Please clarify your question by providing code, or at least specifying in what form your data exists. Is it, for example, a `pandas.DataFrame`? A list of lists, a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

you can use  .isdigit() to check first the value and then convert it to int

Answer (score 0):

if `s` is your `string` value and `n` the `int`, then use :

```
try:
   n = int(s) 
except:
   n = 'NaN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using panda's DataFrame.

```
def convert_str_to_digit(x):
   if x.isdigit():
      return int(x)
   else:
      return np.nan

df['your_column'].apply(convert_str_to_digit, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my implementation:

```
value_list=['04','Or','130.4','AA','','-4']
y_list=[]

for value in value_list:
    try: 
        y_list.append(int(value))
    except:
        y_list.append('nan')
print(y_list) #[4, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', -4]
```